# Ubuntu 14.04lts to ubuntu 16.04 High X.org usage after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, upgrade, xorg

i upgraded my ubuntu server to 16.04lts and after the update the x server is using a very high about of CPU time when viewing anything on Chrome or Firefox or really anything that requires it to draw anything.

ive moved from the open x drivers nouveau which worked perfect on 14.04 to the nvidia 304 drivers and tried using the 361.42 drivers all of them still result in x using the cpu to draw everything

```
flynn@Tron:~/tmp$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 460/PCIe/SSE2
GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_complex_primitives, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_complex_primitives, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap,
```

ive run out of ideas on how to address this issue so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using the Intel integrated GPU has good  performance and substantially better reliability--if you have it that is.

Comment: this is an amd board, i dont think the motherboard even has a video out.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.